# Is there a `dark theme` for https://askubuntu.com similar to whats available on https://stackoverflow.com/

Tags: discussion

Luckily there is a `dark theme` available for https://stackoverflow.com/  as per

[image]

Is there a similar `dark theme` for https://askubuntu.com/  ?    if so how to navigate to engage ?

I am not asking for a desktop theme but one inside the website itself

Comment: No, but you can use the Stylish plugin with the Stack Overflow Dark theme. It looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xqOA25A.png). You can also use one of the many Dark Reader type of browser extensions, though I've not found any that are all that aesthetic for this particular set of sites. They're serviceable, but not the greatest.

Comment: I wanted to come back and update this. I have found [this theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/163575/blender-stack-exchange-dark-theme) which works fairly well. You will have to edit the settings to tell it to work on 'askubuntu.com', but it seems to work with all the SE sites I've tried so far. It's a fairly dark theme, suitable for dark rooms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some new features, such as [following questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232), are very easy to roll out across the entire network. Just update the codebase and it works. Dark Mode is sadly not one of those things; they'll have to go over *all* the sites individually (at least the ones with a custom design) and tweak the colors and images.

Some relevant references: the [announcement of Dark Mode on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4751173):

> #### Future releases
>
> At this point, the focus of Dark Mode is on Stack Overflow and we’ll eventually bring it to MSO. While the retheming we did across the network two years ago makes updating our LESS easier, creating dark versions of all of our sites, particularly the custom-designed ones, is going to be a huge challenge we’re not able to contemplate at this time. The artwork on some of those sites simply can’t be made dark because we don’t have access to the original art files and, to be honest, some of the themes will always be better as-is.

and a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348482/295232) on a community feedback post, with an answer by a staff member:

> Q: You mentioned paying off a lot of technical debt to implement Dark Mode on Stack Overflow. How much of this effort would be useful in expanding Dark Mode to the entire network? For example, would you need to re-implement it mostly from scratch on each individual site, or is there now a Dark Mode Module that can be installed, tested, and tweaked pretty much anywhere you want to with a much smaller amount of effort than was necessary to implement it the first time around for Stack Overflow?
>
> ---
>
> A: From talking to Aaron... it's kinda complicated. We can't just turn a lot of sites dark because their artwork was designed with light mode in mind (excepting for Science Fiction & Fantasy, for the most part). So plopping dark mode on, say... Worldbuilding or English Language Learners or Seasoned Advice... would be pretty impossible without redoing their artwork... again. This is one of those... rare cases where beta sites have a leg up... :)

Ask Ubuntu has a fairly basic theme so it's probably one of the easiest sites to convert, but it will take a while before they'll do it (if they are going to do it at all).